# Unpack Symfony "tagged Services"

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I got a class which accepts multiple `Consumer` implementations as constructor arguments.

I want to "fill in" all my Consumers via the Symfony DI-Container.
I tried injection tagged services.

```
final class SynchronousMessageDispatcher implements MessageDispatcher
{
    /**
     * @var Consumer[]
     */
    private $consumers;

    public function __construct(Consumer ...$consumers)
    {
        $this->consumers = $consumers;
    }
}
```

So I tried to Tag the services in the `services.yml` like that:

```
services:
    _instanceof:
        EventSauce\EventSourcing\Consumer:
            tags: ['eventsauce.consumer']
```

And then inject it like this:

```
eventsauce.message_dispatcher:
    class: EventSauce\EventSourcing\SynchronousMessageDispatcher
    arguments: [!tagged eventsauce.consumer]
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to EventSauce\EventSourcing\SynchronousMessageDispatcher::__construct() must implement interface EventSauce\EventSourcing\Consumer, instance of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\RewindableGenerator given

I fully understand why. Is there a way to **unpack services**

In other words: Is it possible to modify `[!tagged eventsauce.consumer]` somehow. Or is the `...$consumers` syntax incompatible with the Tagged service Injection in Symfony.

Don't get me wrong. I know that I can easily implement `MessageDispatcher` myself. Just wanted to know ;-)

Comment: You'd have to rewrite custom `!tagged` functionality, see this line: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/22200/files#diff-3ba965dae53617e4dc0599b18aab6cb9R34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My original solution**:

As "Tomáš Votruba" mentioned you'd have to rewrite your own `!tagged` functionality. e.g. `!tagged-variadic`.

This is not worth the effort for me. I'd rather implement the class using an `iteratable` ("nifr" explained the benefits, thanks).

For further reading, there is a closed issue on [symfony/symfony#23608](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23608)

**My new solution**

I used [Argument unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) and the [Delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) to use the class the library provided with my tagged services.

Work :-) Hurray.

```
final class TaggedMessageDispatcher implements MessageDispatcher {
    public function __construct(iterable $consumers)
    {
        $this->dispatcher = new SynchronousMessageDispatcher(... $consumers);
    }

    public function dispatch(Message ...$messages): void
    {
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(... $messages);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wrong typehint here.

With the `[!tagged <tag>]` syntax a single `iterable` will be injected - not an undefined number of arguments as expected by the splat operator.

You're actually typehinting for multiple `Consumer` objects as arguments with the splat (`...$arguments`) operator here.

So the answer to your question is:
The splat operator is not compatible with the `[!tagged ..]` syntax.
You'd indeed need to write your own injection type that splits up the tagged services when using a new notation like `[!tagged-call_user_func ..]`.

That said it doesn't really make sense to collect a list of objects, extract them to be function arguments just to let PHP put them back into a list again. I get your idea behind it in terms of code cleanliness though.

Another limitation is the fact that you can't pass multiple variadic arguments to a function. So ...

```
public function __construct(Alpha ...$alphas, Beta ...$betas)
```

... is not possible.

A possible solution/workaround allowing you to keep the typehinting for the collection would be the following:

```
final class SynchronousMessageDispatcher implements MessageDispatcher
{
    /**
     * @var Consumer[]
     */
    private $consumers;

    public function __construct(iterable $consumers)
    {
        foreach($consumers as $consumer) {
          assert($consumer instanceof Consumer, \InvalidArgumentException('..'));
        }

        $this->consumers = $consumers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.
I knew the reason for failing. And I'm not a fan of the "splead", but a library I'm using it uses it. I can make my own implementations of the interfaces, but hoped to get around it somehow.

With your help I found an issue for that.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23608


I will simply write my own implementation of the "MessageDispatcher".